# Printing issue (OFFENDING COMMAND: @PJL) with CUPS to Lexmark MX622ade that is set to PCL language

Tags: printing, cups, postscript, lexmark-printer, pcl

A Lexmark MX622 printer configured to use PCL as default language does not print using CUPS (that seems to prefer PostScript):

I could print a test page (openSUSE Leap 15.4 using YaST2) successfully, but when I print from Firefox, nothing is printed, ecept this error message:

```text
ERROR: undefined
OFFENDING COMMAND: @PJL

STACK:
```

As I understand it, that error is from PostScript, complaining about an unknown `@PJL` command (*Printer Job Language*, I guess).

What confuses me is that I'm using the driver from Lexmark (Lexmark-UPD-PPD-Files-1.0-05252022.x86_64).

The printer definition is:

```cups
<Printer lexmark>
UUID urn:uuid:97dac5eb-0489-3c6a-4574-b1fd40e4490e
Info Lexmark MX622ade
Location Büro
MakeModel Lexmark MX610 Series
DeviceURI socket://lp-REDACTED.de:9100
PortMonitor tbcp
State Idle
StateTime 1666696356
ConfigTime 1666696299
Type 8425684
Accepting Yes
Shared No
JobSheets none none
QuotaPeriod 0
PageLimit 0
KLimit 0
OpPolicy default
ErrorPolicy stop-printer
Attribute marker-colors \#000000,#000000,none
Attribute marker-levels 100,100,100
Attribute marker-names Imaging Unit,Black Cartridge,Maintenance Kit
Attribute marker-types opc,toner,fuser
Attribute marker-change-time 1666696356
</Printer>
```

The PPD identifies itself as (There is no driver for the 620 series):

```ppd
*FormatVersion: "4.3"
*FileVersion: "1.0"
*LanguageVersion: English
*LanguageEncoding: ISOLatin1
*PCFileName: "LXMX610.PPD"
*Product: "(Lexmark MX610 Series)"
*Product: "(Lexmark MX610de)"
*Product: "(Lexmark MX611de)"
*Product: "(Lexmark MX611dhe)"
*Manufacturer: "Lexmark"
*ModelName: "Lexmark MX610 Series"
*ShortNickName: "Lexmark MX610 Series"
*NickName: "Lexmark MX610 Series"
*PSVersion: "(3010.010) 20040929"
```

Can I fix the issue without changing the configuration on the printer?

The PPD contains:

```ppd
*JCLBegin: "<1B>%-12345X@PJL JOB<0A>"
*JCLToPSInterpreter: "@PJL ENTER LANGUAGE = POSTSCRIPT<0A>"
*JCLEnd: "<1B>%-12345X@PJL EOJ <0A><1B>%-12345X"
```

Operating system is openSUSE 15.4 x86-64, CUPS version is cups-2.2.7-150000.3.35.1.x86_64.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the port monitor `tbcp` caused the problem; setting it to `none` allowed printing.